# run script remotely on windows 2012 server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, scripting, remote-desktop-services

I have a script that I manually have to run 4 or 5 times a day, in one of our servers. I remotely access the server and execute the script. 
The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation.
Now, I can´t give remote access to the server to the other users, but I need one of the users to execute this same script. Is there a way, i was thinking of a script, that when that other user executes it, it runs the script lodged in the server?

Answer (score 0):

While totally overkill for your need, Jenkins could provide a web interface to run a "build" that would be your script.  The script could have admin access (as an example) but the user would only have access to Jenkins.

Another option, you could have a parent script running as a schedule task every couple of minutes.  Have it check for the presence of a file in a file share and if that file exists, run the script you want to run.  All that would require is a parent script and a locked down file share.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Going to give it a go with Jenkins. I have a task created in that server to run the script automatically every 15 minutes, thing is it does not run, and I can't get it to run i don't know why...